# How do I create a new column in R that is 1 if a certain value in another column is an outlier?

Tags: r

I want to create a new column that is 1 if the value of a particular column is an outlier. Otherwise, the value should be 0.

An example would be the following:

```
outlier <- c(rnorm(10,0,5),40,-60,rnorm(10,0,5))

        V1
1   -6.273411
2   -6.576979
3   9.256693
4   -2.448468
5   -7.386433
6   -8.922403
7   -1.339524
8   -2.136594
9   -2.271990
10  -6.066499
11  40.000000
12  -60.000000
13  6.697281
14  -3.212984
15  6.950176
16  -7.054237
17  11.820208
18  -1.836457
19  -1.341675
20  -3.271044
21  -10.260103
22  8.239565
```

So, observation 11 and 12 should be clearly outliers:

```
boxplot.stats(outlier)$out

[1]  40 -60
```

What I want to archive is the following:

```
        V1      V2
1   -6.273411   0
2   -6.576979   0
3   9.256693    0
4   -2.448468   0
5   -7.386433   0
6   -8.922403   0
7   -1.339524   0
8   -2.136594   0
9   -2.271990   0
10  -6.066499   0
11  40.000000   1
12  -60.000000  1
13  6.697281    0
14  -3.212984   0
15  6.950176    0
16  -7.054237   0
17  11.820208   0
18  -1.836457   0
19  -1.341675   0
20  -3.271044   0
21  -10.260103  0
22  8.239565    0
```

Is there any elegant way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind there is no universal, agreed definition for what is an "outlier" in all cases. By default, `boxplot` assumes the value is no more than 1.5 times the inter-quartile range away from the .25 and .75 quartiles. You can write your own function which gives you complete control over the definition. For example

```
is_outlier <- function(x) {
  iqr <- IQR(x)
  q <- quantile(x, c(.25, .75))
  x < q[1]-1.5*iqr | x > q[2]+1.5*iqr
}
```

you can use it with your data like

```
is_outlier(outlier)
```

which returns TRUE/FALSE. Which you can convert to 1/0 with `as.numeric(is_outlier(outlier))` or `is_outlier(outlier)+0` if that's really needed.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `%in%` to convert to logical and coerce it back to binary with `as.integer` or `+`

```
+(outlier %in% boxplot.stats(outlier)$out)
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```